# Manipulation on Spark Dataframe row

Tags: apache-spark, dataframe, rdd

I am new in spark, scala etc 
below is my code

```scala
val eventdf = sqlContext.sql("SELECT sensor, data.actor FROM eventTable")

eventdf.map {
  case (r) => (r.getString(0) + count, r.getString(1), count)
}.saveToCassandra("caliper", "event", SomeColumns("sensor", "sendtime", "count"))
```

Here , I wanted to perform some manipulation with `r.getString(1)` and then pass to cassandra for saving.

Comment: Depending on the manipulation, you can do it directly in the DataFrame, such as `eventdf.withColumn("newColumn", col("sensor") + count)`. Can you provide some details on the kind of manipulation you want to perform?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you cannot apply the transformation directly to the dataframe column, I can suggest the following:

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row
import sqlContext.implicits._

val newRDD = eventdf.map {
  case Row(val1: String, val2: String) => 
    // process val2 here and save the result to val2_processed
    (val1 + count, val2_processed, count) 
}

val newDF = newRDD.toDF("col1", "col2", "col3") // If you need to convert it back to DF

newDF.saveToCassandra(...)
```

Comment: hi @Daniel de Paula ,@AlbertoBonsanto thanks for above answer , but facing compilation issue  : not found: value Row  i.e. case Row()

Comment: Row is of which type ? import org.apache.spark.sql.Row  Or import com.datastax.driver.core.Row

Comment: @SwapnilShirke It's `org.apache.spark.sql.Row`. I added the imports to the code snippet

Comment: Add this to your code (outside of current scope, inside an implicit class):`implicit val enc = RowEncoder(df.schema)`